# Problema con imagen - base de datos - IF

Tags: php, base-de-datos, mysqli, imagen, if

tengo este archivos **alta.php**, lo que deberá de hacer el **IF** es ver si el usuario subió imagen o no, para luego almacenarlo en la base de datos o no.
Esto no esta pasando y no le encuentro el problema. 
Les dejo los códigos:

Alta.php

```
$categoria = $_POST['categoria'];
        $titulo = $_POST['titulo'];
        $descripcion = $_POST['descripcion'];
        $codigo = $_POST['codigo'];
// Regalos Empresarial
if($categoria == "regalosempresarial"){

if($_FILES['img1'] == ""){
} else {
// Imagen 1
$folder1 = "Regalos_Empresarial/img1/"; 
$prm1 = array("image/gif","image/jpeg","image/png"); 
$imagen1 = substr(strrchr($image1['name'], "."), 1);
$rutaArchivo1 = md5(rand() * time()) . "$imagen1";
$typ1 = $_FILES["img1"]["type"];
$tmp1 = $_FILES["img1"]["tmp_name"];
if(is_uploaded_file($tmp1)){
    if(in_array($typ1,$prm1)){
    move_uploaded_file($tmp1,$folder1.$rutaArchivo1);
    }
}
$urlnueva_img1 = $folder1.$rutaArchivo1;
// Fin de imgen 1
}

if($_FILES['img2'] == ""){
} else {
// Imagen 2
$folder2 = "Regalos_Empresarial/img2/"; 
$prm2 = array("image/gif","image/jpeg","image/png"); 
$imagen2 = substr(strrchr($image2['name'], "."), 1);
$rutaArchivo2 = md5(rand() * time()) . "$imagen2";
$typ2 = $_FILES["img2"]["type"];
$tmp2 = $_FILES["img2"]["tmp_name"];
if(is_uploaded_file($tmp2)){
    if(in_array($typ2,$prm2)){
    move_uploaded_file($tmp2,$folder2.$rutaArchivo2);
    }
}
$urlnueva_img2 = $folder2.$rutaArchivo2;
// Fin de imgen 2
}

if($_FILES['img3'] == ""){
} else {
// Imagen 3
$folder3 = "Regalos_Empresarial/img3/"; 
$prm3 = array("image/gif","image/jpeg","image/png"); 
$imagen3 = substr(strrchr($image3['name'], "."), 1);
$rutaArchivo3 = md5(rand() * time()) . "$imagen3";
$typ3 = $_FILES["img3"]["type"];
$tmp3 = $_FILES["img3"]["tmp_name"];
if(is_uploaded_file($tmp3)){
    if(in_array($typ3,$prm3)){
    move_uploaded_file($tmp3,$folder3.$rutaArchivo3);
    }
}
$urlnueva_img3 = $folder3.$rutaArchivo3;
// Fin de imgen 3
}

if($_FILES['img4'] == ""){
} else {
// Imagen 4
$folder4 = "Regalos_Empresarial/img4/"; 
$prm4 = array("image/gif","image/jpeg","image/png"); 
$imagen4 = substr(strrchr($image4['name'], "."), 1);
$rutaArchivo4 = md5(rand() * time()) . "$imagen4";
$typ4 = $_FILES["img4"]["type"];
$tmp4 = $_FILES["img4"]["tmp_name"];
if(is_uploaded_file($tmp4)){
    if(in_array($typ4,$prm4)){
    move_uploaded_file($tmp4,$folder4.$rutaArchivo4);
    }
}
$urlnueva_img4 = $folder4.$rutaArchivo4;
// Fin de imgen 4
}

if($_FILES['img5'] == ""){
} else {
// Imagen 5
$folder5 = "Regalos_Empresarial/img5/"; 
$prm5 = array("image/gif","image/jpeg","image/png"); 
$imagen5 = substr(strrchr($image5['name'], "."), 1);
$rutaArchivo5 = md5(rand() * time()) . "$imagen5";
$typ5 = $_FILES["img5"]["type"];
$tmp5 = $_FILES["img5"]["tmp_name"];
if(is_uploaded_file($tmp5)){
    if(in_array($typ5,$prm5)){
    move_uploaded_file($tmp5,$folder5.$rutaArchivo5);
    }
}
$urlnueva_img5 = $folder5.$rutaArchivo5;
// Fin de imgen 5
}

// coneccion
$data = "connect.php";
include ($data);
$query2 = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO Regalos_Empresarial (titulo,img1,img2,img3,img4,img5,descripcion,codigo) values ('".$titulo."','".$urlnueva_img1."','".$urlnueva_img2."','".$urlnueva_img3."','".$urlnueva_img4."','".$urlnueva_img5."','".$descripcion."','".$codigo."')");
mysqli_close($con);
header ("Location: productos.php");
// Fin de coneccion

}
```

Es un pedazo del Código.

Si por esas casualidad ven algún error que no pude a ver notado, van a ser bien tomado.

Saludos

Comment: Deverias agregar el html del formulario y el ajax o lo que estes usando

Comment: ¿Tienes indicado el enctype dentro del form?, algo así: `<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="tu-archivo.php"></form>`

Comment: El archivo Nuevo Producto.php contiene este formulario:
<form action="alta.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1">
  Titulo de Producto:<br>
  <label>
  <input name="titulo" type="text" id="titulo">
  </label> 
  <p>Imagen:<br>
    <label>
    <input name="img1" type="file" id="img1">
    </label>
    <br>
    <label>
    <input name="img2" type="file" id="img2">
    </label>
    <br>
..........
No me deja poner el resto del formularo, asi que te dejo la mitad de la parte.